# Issues with using too many Threads a benchmark program

Tags: java, multithreading, benchmarking, multicore

I've programmed a (very simple) benchmark in Java. It simply increments a double value up to a specified value and takes the time.

When I use this singlethreaded or with a low amount of threads (up to 100) on my 6-core desktop, the benchmark returns reasonable and repeatable results.

But when I use for example 1200 threads, the average multicore duration is significantly lower than the singlecore duration (about 10 times or more). I've made sure that the total amount of incrementations is the same, no matter how much threads I use.

Why does the performance drop so much with more threads?  Is there a trick to solve this problem?

I'm posting my source, but I don't think, that there is a problem.

Benchmark.java:

```
package sibbo.benchmark;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Benchmark implements TestFinishedListener {
            private static final double TARGET = 1e10;
    private static final int THREAD_MULTIPLICATOR = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Benchmark b = new Benchmark(TARGET);
        b.start();
    }

    private int coreCount;
    private List<Worker> workers = new LinkedList<>();
    private List<Worker> finishedWorkers = new LinkedList<>();
    private double target;

    public Benchmark(double target) {
        this.target = target;
        getSystemInfos();
        printInfos();
    }

    private void getSystemInfos() {
        coreCount = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    }

    private void printInfos() {
        System.out.println("Usable cores: " + coreCount);
        System.out.println("Multicore threads: " + coreCount *                 THREAD_MULTIPLICATOR);
        System.out.println("Loops per core: " + new DecimalFormat("###,###,###,###,##0").format(TARGET));

        System.out.println();
    }

    public synchronized void start() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);

        System.out.print("Initializing singlecore benchmark... ");
        Worker w = new Worker(this, 0);
        workers.add(w);

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("finished");

        System.out.print("Running singlecore benchmark... ");
        w.runBenchmark(target);
        wait();

        System.out.println("finished");
        printResult();

        System.out.println();
        // Multicore
        System.out.print("Initializing multicore benchmark...  ");
        finishedWorkers.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < coreCount * THREAD_MULTIPLICATOR; i++) {
            workers.add(new Worker(this, i));
        }

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("finished");

        System.out.print("Running multicore benchmark...  ");

        for (Worker worker : workers) {
            worker.runBenchmark(target / THREAD_MULTIPLICATOR);
        }

        wait();

        System.out.println("finished");
        printResult();

        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
    }

    private void printResult() {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###,##0.000");

        long min = -1, av = 0, max = -1;
        int threadCount = 0;
        boolean once = true;

        System.out.println("Result:");

        for (Worker w : finishedWorkers) {
            if (once) {
                once = false;

                min = w.getTime();
                max = w.getTime();
            }

            if (w.getTime() > max) {
                max = w.getTime();
            }

            if (w.getTime() < min) {
                min = w.getTime();
            }

            threadCount++;
            av += w.getTime();

            if (finishedWorkers.size() <= 6) {
                System.out.println("Worker " + w.getId() + ": " + df.format(w.getTime() / 1e9) + "s");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Min: " + df.format(min / 1e9) + "s, Max: " + df.format(max / 1e9) + "s, Av per Thread: "
                + df.format((double) av / threadCount / 1e9) + "s");
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void testFinished(Worker w) {
        workers.remove(w);
        finishedWorkers.add(w);

        if (workers.isEmpty()) {
            notify();
        }
    }
}
```

Worker.java:

```
package sibbo.benchmark;

public class Worker implements Runnable {
    private double value = 0;
    private long time;
    private double target;
    private TestFinishedListener l;
    private final int id;

    public Worker(TestFinishedListener l, int id) {
        this.l = l;
        this.id = id;

        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public synchronized void runBenchmark(double target) {
        this.target = target;
        notify();
    }

    public long getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synWait();
        value = 0;
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        while (value < target) {
            value++;
        }

        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        time = endTime - startTime;

        l.testFinished(this);
    }

    private synchronized void synWait() {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming your asking for an explanation of _why_ it is performing like this?

Comment: Any chance you are running out of memory when you are running with 1200 threads?  Can you watch your application with jconsole and see if the memory graphs show full eden and survivor spaces?  You may need to increase memory available with -Xmx

Comment: Yes that's what I'm interested in.

Comment: I know that the javavm uses about 75MB memory when running this. I've never used jconsole, so I'll first set the maximum amount of memory to a higher value.

Comment: The important thing to realise is that each thread will consume a fixed amount of stack space memory. IIRC, 512k (but configurable via -Xss). So a huge number of threads will consume a large amount of memory regardless of the work the threads are doing

Comment: k, I've runned the program with -Xmx1g. Using 1200 Threads, it used 77MB, using 12000 Threads, it uses about 650MB. Using 1200 Threads the measured times are 17.5 and 13.5, using 12000 the times are 17.5 and 0.015.

Comment: @Sibbo Its all fine with benchmarking wierd stuff, dont get me wrong. But I hope you're not going to create threads munally in a real application. As you probably see, its trivial to over-parallelize. If you want multi-threading in your application, use the Executor interface. It works with a thread-pool, mapping your Runnables to worker threads. Especially useful when you have A LOT of possibly parallel tasks. I would go as far as saying: Manual thread ccreation considered harmful.

Comment: Before I create real big aplications I will study computer science,  so ;)

Answer (score 6):

You need to understand that the OS (or Java thread scheduler, or both) is trying to balance between all of the threads in your application to give them all a chance to perform some work, and there is a non-zero cost to switch between threads.  With 1200 threads, you have just reached (and probably far exceeded) the tipping point wherein the processor is spending more time context switching than doing actual work.

Here is a rough analogy:

You have one job to do in room A.  You stand in room A for 8 hours a day, and do your job.

Then your boss comes by and tells you that you have to do a job in room B also.  Now you need to periodically leave room A, walk down the hall to room B, and then walk back.  That walking takes 1 minute per day.  Now you spend 3 hours, 59.5 minutes working on each job, and one minute walking between rooms.

Now imagine that you have 1200 rooms to work in.  You are going to spend more time walking between rooms than doing actual work.  This is the situation that you have put your processor into.  It is spending so much time switching between contexts that no real work gets done.

EDIT: Now, as per the comments below, maybe you spend a fixed amount of time in each room before moving on- your work will progress, but the number of context switches between rooms still affects the overall runtime of a single task.

Comment: Agreed - With enough threads, the box will spend more time jumping between them than it gets to spend actually running them.

Comment: Doesn't explaing why singlecore version suffers less from the exceeding amount of threads

Comment: @Evgeni I assume the OP is misusing the term "single core" to mean "single threaded" here, based on his use of that term in the code.

Comment: No, it won't, or at least, it shouldn't.  Once the OS has more than twice as many ready threads as there are cores, the rate of context-switching cannot get any higher.  it shouldn't matter whether there are 8 or 800 ready, CPU-intensive threads on a 4-core box - at every interrupt, 4 threads will be preempted and replaced with 4 others from the head of the ready queue for the priority set, shoving the oold threads at the tail.  The only issue that may come up is, if the threads are not created with an appropriate stack size, there may be memory swapping issues with the thread stacks.

Comment: @ChrisShain Agreed, after reviewing his code more carefully. Sorry!

Comment: OTOH, looking at the code, the OP is micro-managing the threads and continually creating them, not pooling them, adding them in and out of lists etc.

Comment: @MartinJames Keep in mind that these are Java-Threads, handeled and scheduled by the JVM, nnot the OS

Comment: Chris are you sure of this?  What is your source?  As I read the thread scheduler documentation, the time slice is _not_ effected by the number of threads in the run queue.  So as the number of threads increase, there should _not_ be an increase in context switching overhead.  @Martin, didn't you do some analysis on this?  I can't find the question we were dealing with though.

Comment: The length of the time slice may not be affected, but if the time slice granted is less than the amount of time needed to complete a task, then the number of context switches performed before that task is re-scheduled becomes relevant.

Comment: To leverage my example above, if I always spend 30 minutes in any given room and it takes me 1 minute to switch between rooms, I can complete 2 90-minute tasks (180 minutes of work) in 90 + 90 + 5 = 185 minutes, but the first task takes 154 minutes (90 on that task + 60 on the second task + 4 context switches). If I have 3 rooms, I can complete 3 90-minute tasks in 270 + 8 = 278 minutes, but the first task takes 226 minutes (90 on that task, 60 on the second task, and 60 on the third task + 6 context switches).  The effects of additional context switches are non-linear to the execution time.

Comment: Finally, if I have 1000 90-minute tasks, the first task will be done in 62030 minutes- 90 spent on that task, 60 each on tasks 2-1000, and 2000 context switches.

Comment: Yup, so that's 2000 context-switches in 62030 minutes, 0.032 switches/minute.  The first example has 6 switches in 278 minutes, 0.021 switches /minute.  There's not much difference, considering the huge difference in the number of tasks and the jitter introduced in the first example with the small number of tasks.  Assuming that the tasks are CPU-intensive and take some reasonable time, the switch overhead just cannot increase beyond that incurred at every interrupt that causes a reschedule.  If it's not entered, the OS cannot change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I've found my problem, but until now, no solution.

When measuring the time every thread runs to do his part of the work, there are different possible minimums for different total amounts of threads. The maximum is the same everytime. In case that a thread is started first and then is paused very often and finishes last. For example this maximum value could be 10 seconds. Assuming that the total amount of operations that is done by every thread stays the same, no matter how much threads I use, the amount of operations that is done by a single thread has to be changed when using a different amount of threads. For example, using one thread, it has to do 1000 operations, but using ten threads, everyone of them has to do just 100 operations. Now, using ten threads, the minimum amount of time that one thread can use is much lower than using one thread. So calculating the average amount of time every thread needs to do his work is nonsense. The minimum using ten Threads would be 1 second. This happens if one thread does its work without interruption.

**EDIT**

The solution would be to simply measure the amount of time between the start of the first thread and the completion of the last.

Comment: The more threads per core you have the longer each thread takes to complete. Even the end to end time should increase once you have much mroe threads than cores.